# 「〜てもらおう」の意味は何ですか。

Tags: subsidiary-verbs, volitional-form, giving-and-receiving

「〜てもらう」の文法は知っていますが、この下の文章の「〜てもらおう」の意味がわかりませんでした。

> 例）「一度に全部わかっ**てもらおう**なんて、思っちゃいない。」

この「〜てもらおう」を説明していただけませんか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: one small problem with the lack of context here. 　わかる can mean to understand something, or to "accept the truth" of something. Without context it's hard (for me) to be sure which is meant in this example sentence. I think it makes more sense as "accept" but not sure if this is what is confusing you, or something else about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「〜てもらう」 has a basic meaning of "get / make / induce (someone) to do (something)"

In the case of **わかる**, the form 分かってもらう could mean either "make it understood / make you understand (something)" or "make you accept (something)".

When you further conjugate this with the volitional **おう** ending, which indicates a potential future act, 分かってもら**おう** ends up meaning something like "intend to make you understand/accept" or more simply "will get you to understand/accept".

The inclusion of 全部 in the example sentence makes me think this わかる is probably meant to talk about "understanding", so...

> 「一度に全部わかって**もらおう**なんて、思っちゃいない。」

would mean something like

> 'I'm not thinking, "**I'll get (someone/you)** to understand everything all at once."'

or more fluidly in English:

> "I'm not planning to make you learn everything all at once."